# Unauthorized error when using GitLab Private Token to call GitLab endpoint

Tags: gitlab, dotnet-httpclient, unauthorized

I am trying to reach GitLab API endpoint via HttpClient. Firstly, I am generating private access token with

```
https://gitlab.example.com/oauth/token
```

then with this access token I'm trying to reach tags or projects with endpoints below

```
https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/1/repository/tags/

https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/
```

Without using access token I can reach public information, but when using the token it gives **401 Unauthorized error**. I even tried private token inside url, it gives same error too.

```
https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/1/repository/tags?private_token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

My code is below

```
private async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetHttpResponse(string url)
{
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3
                                                | SecurityProtocolType.Tls
                                                | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11
                                                | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, url);
    request.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue(MediaTypeJson));
    request.Headers.Add("Private-Token", accessToken);

    return await Client.SendAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

I do not know what is wrong and how to fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to send the oauth headers too

`curl --header "Authorization: Bearer <your_access_token>" https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects`

try it

Comment: Thank you adding authorization instead of private token to header worked for me `request.Headers.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {accessToken}");`

Answer (score 0):

Use like this will give you projects of group and subgroup projects

```
curl --silent --header "Private-Token: YOUR_GITLAB_TOKEN" https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/groups/<group_ID>/projects?include_subgroups=true
```

or if you only want projects from specific group

```
curl --silent --header "Private-Token: YOUR_GITLAB_TOKEN" https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/groups/<group_ID>/projects?per_page=100
```